# Как сделать срез для строки и сформировать список всех срезов

Tags: python, синтаксис

Как сделать срез для строки ?
Срез начинается после слова " "title": " и заканчивается после первой запятой - ",".
В итоге должен быть сформирован список всех срезов.

Пример: первый срез и первый элемент в списке - "Холодильник Side by Side".
Уточнение - элемент с кавычками, это все первый элемент, а не только текст без кавычек.

В строке встречается много раз слово -  "title"

```
[<form action="/fater/json/productlist?type=PRODUCT_LIST" class="js-ajax-request" data-ajax='{"url":"/fater/json/productlist?type=PRODUCT_LIST" ,  "requestParamSeries": [{"name":"standardFilters","checkFor":"values"},{"name":"rangeFilters","checkFor":"minValue","checkFor2":"maxValue"}], "dataRendering":true, "method":"POST"}' data-ajax-id="ajax-productlist" data-current-state-ajax-uri="/fater/json/productlist?categoryString=outletproducts&amp;type=PRODUCT_LIST" id="command" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"><script data-init-data="ajax-productlist" data-no-initial-callup="true" type="application/json">
                        {"response":{"cheap":"0","expensive":"0","items":[{"productIndex":"0","sku":"KA90IVI20R","type":"shop","title":"Холодильник Side by Side","isInComparison":false,"comparable":true,"productsInComparisonSize":0,"headers":["iQ500","Холодильник Side by Side","","177 x 91 cm","Inox-easyclean","KA90IVI20R"],"price":{"value":164990.0,"displayValue":"164 990,00 ₽"},"stockStatus":{"trafficLight":"green","text":"[G11]","buyable":true,"permanentlyNotAvailable":false},"link":"/fater/outlet/KA90IVI20R?breadcrumb=","productImage":{"src":"//media3.123.com/Product_Shots/{width}x{height}/MCSA00762608_E6797_KA90IVI20G_407519_def.jpg","alt":"KA90IVI20R"},"hookline":"Холодильник coolDuo серии iQ 500 типа \"side-by-side\" с технологией NoFrost, дополнительно оснащен дозатором для воды и льда.","keyBenefits":["Многопоточная система охлаждения multiAirflow обеспечивает равномерное распределение воздуха и охлаждение на всех уровнях холодильника.","Технология noFrost защищает от образования инея и избавит вас от необходимости размораживать холодильник.","Холодильник шириной 70см - существенное увеличение полезного объема для хранения продуктов.","Функция superFreezing понижает температуру на заданный промежуток времени, чтобы быстрее заморозить только что добавленные продукты.","Функция superCooling, или 'суперохлаждение', уменьшает температуру на заданное время,
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут достаточно много вариантов решения

1. Используйте регулярные выражения для решения вашей задачи. [Regex and Python](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/)
2. Десериализуйте строку и достаньте нужный вам параметр. [JSON and Python](https://python-scripts.com/json)
3. (плохой вариант) используйте split для разделения строки по " "title": " а потом по первой запятой. [Split and Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Вот вам рабочий вариант регулярного выражения : `"title":("[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я ]*")`

а вот пример:
https://regex101.com/r/wDy78P/1

Comment: Покажите,пожалуйста,как 2 и 3 пункт оформить в виде скрипта.Что бы я мог его скопировать и запустить. Потому что иначе не понятно.

Comment: К счастью или к сожалению на питоне я не пишу и проверить код не имею возможности. Все варианты которые я вам предоставил реализуемы на питоне. Ссылки для большего понимания способа решения я добавлю к своему ответу.